# Gas senor sensitivity characteristics

Tags: air, sensors

the gas sensor can detect multiple gases. but at a given time, if its detecting multiple gas concentration, then the net resistance should indicate total gas concentration. And if that's the case , then we cannot find concentration of a single gas from given graph. how to find concentration then ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZhmS.png)

Comment: Hi vedika! Welcome :) Can you detail what language you are using and include any relevant code and/or error messages in your question? This will help in finding a solution.

See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around structuring questions. And [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.